# Google Maps API Key Programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

It makes no sense to me that the Google Maps API  Key is required to live in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

There is no way to programmatically modify this file on run-time?

So for each client that is using my Android App... I'm required to have a separate build process for each, just because of the Google Maps API Key?

Comment: `So for each client that is using my Android App... I'm required to have a separate build process for each, just because of the Google Maps API Key?` not right

Comment: @Ibrahim ok.. so how is swapping the key done?

Comment: declaring the api key inside manifest make you able to use map with the same api in whole application, without generating api for each client.

Comment: No - I meant for each user of my App. My customers are each going to have a different API key. How do I swap this out per customer?

Comment: Mhmhm, i got you, i don't know, but i think it's not legal to do that since the api required in compile time and can't change during run-time.

Comment: I am wondering why do you need a separate API key for each user of your app? Google Maps Android API has unlimited quota, so what is the point?

Comment: @xomena i think he need to separate api in order to make customer (who will buy the app) put his own api one....

Comment: Yep, but with unlimited quota does it make sense to enter an API key per user?

Comment: @xomena i think he didn't mean that, he need to make it programaticaly because while developing he using his own api keys, after he deliver the application to customer he want to make him can change the api key to it's own one..

Comment: @xomena where is unlimited quota documented? I thought it was paid after a certain number of views. thanks!

Comment: You can see this in the developer console as shown in my screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/shA0c

Comment: @xomena i'm confused. looks like you have a have a premium plan to release for production? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#key-std-details

Comment: @aherrick No, I don't have Premium plan. This is a Standard plan project. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits. It reads: "The following APIs do not have usage limits: Google Maps Android API, Google Maps SDK for iOS, Google Maps Embed API"

Comment: It's crazy such needed flexibility/use case is not covered. But it is possible to set the key programmatically using the Javascript API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update `AndroidManifest.xml`.

However there isn't a need to swap out keys as Google Maps for Android/iOS doesn't have usage limits.